# issue with ajax doesnt continue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have one issue with ajax when I get `echo success` on my php. I don't get execute the first if

```
if(text[0]==="success")
```

Code inside php

```
 if(count($error)==0)
        {
            $user = ORM::for_table('usuario')->create();
            $user->username = $username;
            $user->contrasenia = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $user->email = $email;
            $user->admin = $is_admin;
            $user->save();
            echo "success";
        }
        else 
        {
            $error = json_encode($error);
            echo $error;
        }
```

My code in ajax

```
[![$("#create-button").on('click', function(event){
   //cancels the form submission
   event.preventDefault();
   submitForm();
});

function submitForm()
{
    var dataString = $("#userForm").serialize();;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/altausers",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(text)
        {
           console.log("hola");
           console.log(text);

           if(text\[0\]==="success")
           {
               alert("hola");
                //$("#error").addClass('hidden');
           }
           else if(text.length > 0)
           {

               $("#error").removeClass('hidden');

               texterror = "<ol type='disc'>";
               $.each(text,function(index,value)
               {
                   texterror+="<li>"+value+"</li>";
               });
               texterror+="</ol>";
               document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = texterror;
           }
        }
    });

}
```

---

Image console

[image]

What is the problem?

Could say me which it is problem?

I have that convert the message success to json too

Comment: `$error` is an array??

Comment: as the multi color error message in console says that its an object whereas second time in black says it is a  string, in case of string you are not accessing it properly

Comment: One more thing `if(text\[0\])` will give error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the success echo with

```
 echo json_encode(["success"]);
```

or leave echo the same and replace if in ajax

```
if(text == "success")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that it is an array, so you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items.php",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "command" : "getItems" }
}).success(function( response ) {
    alert( response.fruits.apple );
    alert(Object.keys(response).length); 
});
```

And if you want to see the results:

```
Object.keys( response ).forEach(function( key ) {
    console.log('key name: ', key);
    console.log('value: ', response[key]);
});
```